# Segmentation Fault in ruby when using heroku even though project is django-based

Tags: ruby, heroku, segmentation-fault, abort

I have searched the internet far and wide and have tried many, many proposed solutions, but this problem still persists. My heroku project is Django-based, but these errors are all ruby-based (which I don't even program in anyway). When I push to heroku or run heroku status (or any heroku command in my OSX terminal), I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:74: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Abort trap
```

When I run bundle install in a ruby project directory, I get the following error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/./Users/mycomp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

along with control frame and backtrace information.

Not sure what is relevant, but:

-Previously I had also been getting a libssl error which seems to have gone away when I installed openssl 
-From what I have read, the segmentation fault error stems from a problem with ruby's C compiler. None of the solutions I found online worked to solve that.
-At one point I deleted and reinstalled XCode which might have affected the gcc/c compiler
-I reinstalled ruby with this command 
    rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin 
-I deleted and reinstalled the one gemset on my computer
-I also tried this fix which didn't work:
    rvm gemset empty
    rvm use ree@my-gemset
    gem install bundler
    bundle install

I don't actually code in ruby (just had one test app)-->could I just delete it from heroku/vendor and from my computer to solve the problem? Would prefer to fix it but am more concerned with making sure I can use heroku with my Django project.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Abort trap segmentation fault with ruby when using heroku OSX terminal commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200807/abort-trap-segmentation-fault-with-ruby-when-using-heroku-osx-terminal-commands)