# Abort trap segmentation fault with ruby when using heroku OSX terminal commands

Tags: ruby, ssl, heroku, segmentation-fault

Note: I'm not even using ruby (using django), but ruby is in my computer's path so it seems to be bringing up errors.

When I run any heroku commands (heroku status, heroku login), I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/excon-0.14.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:74: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Abort trap
```

even though ruby -v returns:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

and I did rvm remove ruby-1.8.7.

Anyone know of a fix? Have searched far and wide to no avail. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Apple deprecated the use of OpenSSL in OSX Lion.

You have to specify where to find the new location for openssl.

If you're using Macports:

```
port install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 -C --with-openssl-dir=/opt/local
rvm use 1.9.3
```

If you're using Homebrew:

```
brew install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 -C --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
rvm use 1.9.3
```

Another options is to build OpenSSL as a package in RVM:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 -C --with-openssl-dir=~/.rvm/usr
rvm use 1.9.3
```

this should work for any build of Ruby, just replace the version number.

Comment: I was having this problem under Mountain Lion. I tried the suggested solution to install it as a package in RVM, but that did not work. Luckily the first solution (via Macports) did! Thanks!

Comment: I am running Lion and the second solution (building OpenSSL as a package in RVM) worked flawlessly.  Thanks!